# TimerTask Fragment error in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, timertask

I'm trying to run code which has TimerTask, but running into some errors.
my MainActivity is http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/
and i'm calling a fragment which does some animation which has this Timertask. Everything is working fine, but when I selected different fragment from list item i'm running into TimerTask error.

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       while(true)
       {try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTextView();

            }
        });
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

 }
```

Logcat trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.Project.HomeAnimation$MyTimerTask.run(HomeAnimation.java:53)
at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Any more specifics on what this TimerTask error is? Do you have any logcat trace you can show us? The answer is normally in there

Comment: logcat trace added to original question.

Comment: Is the TextView that you are updating still visible/declared? I would debug the updateTextView and try to if something is null there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the while loop somehow. Maybe set a class flag to false in `onDestroy` and the while loop becomes `while(flag)`:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       flag = true;
       while(flag && (getActivity() != null))
       {try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTextView();

            }
        });
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

 }
```

And your `onDestroy` method would look like:

```
public void onDestroy() {
    flag = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Don't forget to declare the `flag` in your fragment class:

```
private boolean flag = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Gunar, great idea, i'm new to android programming. How can i call class flag to false? ..... public void onDestroy(){ super.onDestory()}

Comment: Edited the answer. I've declared the flag, set it to true when the timer starts and then set it to false in onDestroy. Don't forget to upvote if the answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Handler` in combination with a `Runnable`:

```
 Handler hander = new Handler();


// Your runnable that will be triggered.
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {

           // do stuff

           // post it again
           handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
       }
    };

// Start
hander.post(runnable);


// Stop
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a fragment, the easiest way is to check if current fragment is visible by calling isVisible() method :

```
  @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isVisible()) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                   // stuff to do

                }
            });
        }
    }
```